# can we get the touched subview properties from scroll view in ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subview

I have added 20 subviews to `scrollview` line by line as rows

```
yPos=0;
    for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {

    UIView *timeView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71, yPos, 909, 60)];
    timeView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    timeView.exclusiveTouch=YES;
    timeView.tag=i;
    NSLog(@"sub vieww tag=:%d",timeView.tag);
    timeView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    UILabel *lbltime=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 60)];
    lbltime.text=@"VIEW HERE";
    lbltime.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
  //  [timeView addSubview:lbltime];
    [scrlView addSubview:timeView];

    yPos=yPos+61;
}
```

Now when ever I tap on a subview I am not getting the tapped subview properties.

like coordinates. It is giving parent view coordinates

I enabled subview `UserInteractionEnabled` to Yes.

Can any one tell me how to get tapped subview coordinate and tag value?

Comment: add tap gesture to views you are adding and along with add tag to those views and identify view based on the tag in tapgetsure event method.

Comment: I would recommend you edit the post to show the code you're using to handle the tap.  If you're using a tap gesture recognizer what it is attached to -- the subviews or the scrollview or what?

Comment: in tapgetsure event how to get tapped view.`UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                          action:@selector(tap:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];`In event `-(void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {  ....}`   How to get that tapped view.I already set tags for every subview

Comment: I added SubView to ScrollView and the Scroll view added to parent view

Comment: UIView *v = recognizer.view;
 int tagNum = [v tag]; tagNum is your tag of the tapped view.

Comment: thanks for reply.But i am getting tag value as 0..

Comment: check my answer you are adding tap on self, you should add it on view's in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO NOT subclass from `UIScrollView`, that's exactly why there are gesture recognizers. Also, DO NOT add a separate gesture recognizer to each view.

Add one gesture recognizer to your scroll view, and when it's clicked use the x,y values of the touch to calculate which view was clicked.
You'll need to do a small calculation: `(y value of the click + UIScrollView y offset) / 60`.
60 is the height of each view. This should return the index of the clicked view.

**EDIT:**

Code example:

```
- (void)viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    CGPoint coords = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    int clickedViewIndex = (self.offset.y + coords.y) / 60;

    // now clickedViewIndex contains the index of the clicked view
}
```

Comment: Eli ganem i can u explain briefly

Answer (score 1):

```
           UIView *v = recognizer.view; 
            int tagNum = [v tag];

            Using the tagNum you can do your further operatins.
        Or v is your object of tapped view.

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)]; 
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
[timeview addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    Add this in for loop only.
```

Comment: i got another problem.How to add a view on that subviews of scroll views?

Comment: [subview addSubView:view];

Comment: in my scroll view there are 20 subviews.how to add a view on any two or three subviews.these subviews are already subviews of scroll view

Comment: UIView *view=(UIView *)[subview viewWithTag:viewTagNumber];

Answer (score 0):

Make a class extending UIScrollView :

For example :

```
.h file :

@protocol CustomScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
// optional becuase we always don't want to interact with ScrollView

- (void) customScrollViewTouchesEnded :(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

- (void) customScrollViewDidScroll;


@end

@interface CustomScrollView : UIScrollView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<CustomScrollViewDelegate> touchDelegate;
// delegate was giving error becuase name is already there in UIScrollView 

@end
```

Code for .m file :

```
#import "CustomScrollView.h"

@implementation CustomScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
    if (!self.dragging) {
        //NSLog(@"touchesEnded in custom scroll view");
        if (_touchDelegate != nil) {
            if ([_touchDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customScrollViewTouchesEnded:withEvent:)]) {
                [_touchDelegate customScrollViewTouchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        // it wouldn't be called becuase at the time of dragging touches responding stops.
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }

}

@end
```

Implementing this use subview of scroll view, it will work

```
for (UILabel *label in [customScrollView subviews]) { // change name of table here
    if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        if (label.tag == savedtag) { // use your tag
            // write the code as desired
        }
    } 
}
```